# Ignoring NA for confidence interval (CI)

Tags: r, na, confidence-interval

I am wanting to get the confidence intervals for a vector in R but I have a NA values and want to ignore the NA. I have `na.rm = T` but doesn't work.

Here is my vector and what I have tried:

```
myvector <- c(60.558,60.680,60.757,60.750,60.708, 60.738, NA, 61.103,60.702,60.436)
CIvector <- CI(myvector,na.rm=T)
```

I get an error message:

> 'Error in 1 - ci : non-numeric argument to binary operator'

From what I can tell it is because the CI function doesn't support NA.RM.
If I do not use NA,RM I only NA for all the interval values

Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: what package is `CI()` from? It doesn't appear to be part of base R ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your vector in `na.omit()`:

```
> CIvector <- CI(na.omit(myvector))
> CIvector
   upper     mean    lower 
60.85270 60.71467 60.57663
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `complete.cases`.  There is no `na.rm` argument in `Rmisc::CI`

```
Rmisc::CI(myvector[complete.cases(myvector)])
#   upper     mean    lower 
#60.85270 60.71467 60.57663
```